# Ensure Title of Rich Box Control is on the same page when printing or saving as PDF

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

Here's a problem we've been struggling with for awhile:

We are automating a report so that instead of using offline Microsoft Word forms, users will fill out an InfoPath 2013 web-form to populate 15+ content fields and submit the report in a standardized format.

The fields are all rich text boxes, and each rich text box is located in the right column of a 2x17 table. The left column of the 2x17 table is the title of each rich text box, so they stay aligned and (hopefully!) on the same page.

The problem is, if a user fills out the rich text box so that the contents do not fit on the remainder of the page, when printing InfoPath "pushes" the rich text box to the next page without "pushing" the title for that text box (that is in the same row on the table) to the next page as well.

Any ideas on how ensure a rich text box's title stays on the same page as the rich text box?? Below is a screen shot of the problem. Thanks!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

InfoPath 2013 allows insertion of Page Break into the forms. You need to break the single table into multiple tables, one per page and insert page breaks in-between them. It is upto you to determine how many rich text fields do you want to keep in a single page so that they could accommodate the maximum number of input the user might have.

Regards

Comment: You can also use conditional formatting on the page break to only show it if specific fields that you know only sometimes push the page into two parts happen (too many characters, multiple choices, sections that are displayed instead of collapsed, etc.